# AWS SES Virtual Deliverability Manager Dashboard only shows selective messages

Tags: amazon-web-services, phpmailer, amazon-ses, smtplib

I use AWS SES for outbound messaging for a web service. This includes things like new account sign-up, reset password requests, contact us form and sending out an email w/ PDF attachment(s).

I am leveraging the SES Virtual Deliverability Manager in order to learn more about my sender reputation, track bounces, etc. They recently released a new feature of their Dashboard that will show the list of emails that have been sent via your SES account/credentials (subject, date, to/from, ISP, etc).

I use `PHPMailer` and Python `smtplib` and `email` libraries to send emails across two different EC2 servers (all leveraging the same exact settings for SMTP credentials, host port and TLS encryption).

For some reason, ONLY emails that do **not** have a BCC field show up in the Virtual Deliverability Manager's Dashboard feature. It doesn't matter if I'm sending it via `PHPMailer` or `Python`.

All emails are sent fine and deliverability is **not** an issue but it seems either there is a bug with Virtual Deliverability Manager's Dashboard feature or I'm doing something else wrong that is causing them to not be logged via the service.

Does anyone have any insight into this fairly new service?

Comment: I think this is a bug but I'll double check... I've heard someone else having the same issue and the docs don't mention anything - might be one that I need to check with AWS support.

Comment: Can you post this question on https://repost.aws and update here with an answer from the team? Or I can cross-post for you if you like.

Comment: Yes, I just posted it on repost.aws , if I get an answer I’ll post back here.